# how to remove array when i uncheck some of my checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox, datatables

if i uncheck checkbox value of uncheck checkbox still passes to print.php i want to remove the value of uncheck checkbox from array. i want to print a specific data only if the user mis-checked the checkbox he/she can always unchecked it.

Comment: Did you review the tags you've selected?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue including relevant HTML with which your JS script is interacting. This has nothing to do with PHP or MySQL as far as I can see - I updated your tags. You can [edit] your question. See also [ask]. Thankyou

Comment: The question is not very clear. Please add details about what you are trying to do. Is the issue with the PHP processor or the submission to that page?